# Shortest path from BitmapSource to DX11 Texture2D

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

Does anyone know a way to get from (WPF) System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource to a DX11 Texture2D without going to System.Drawing.Bitmap? I'm trying to strip out all System.Drawing references as this code it for WPF only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Texture2D Bitmap2Texture(Device device, BitmapSource source) {
  var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(source);
  bitmap.Lock();
  var texture = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription() {
    Width = source.PixelWidth,
    Height = source.PixelHeight,
    ArraySize = 1,
    MipLevels = 1,
    BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
    Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
  }, new DataRectangle(bitmap.BackBuffer, bitmap.BackBufferStride));
  bitmap.Unlock();
  return texture;
}
```

You might need to change the texture description flags depending on what you need the texture for.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to load a bitmap source in, I dont use the system windows media library at all but the directx (it may leverage the very same library underneath).

This works in UWP which is what I assume you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

```
   public static D3D11.Texture2D1 CreateTex2DFromBitmap(SharpDX.WIC.BitmapSource bsource, D3D11.Device3 a_device, D3D11.DeviceContext2 a_context, D3D11.Texture2DDescription1 a_desc, int a_mipLevels)
    {
        D3D11.Texture2D1 t2d = null;

        try
        {
            int stride = bsource.Size.Width * 4;
            var buffer = new DataStream(bsource.Size.Height * stride, true, true);

            if (a_mipLevels != 0)
            {
                // if we arent doing mip maps, then load the resource directly
                DataRectangle rect = new DataRectangle(buffer.DataPointer, stride);
                bsource.CopyPixels(stride, buffer);
                t2d = new D3D11.Texture2D1(a_device, a_desc, rect); /// this creates a texture and populates it, we need to create a blank one then populate it.                
            }
            else
            {
                t2d = new D3D11.Texture2D1(a_device, a_desc); /// this creates a texture and populates it, we need to create a blank one then populate it.
                bsource.CopyPixels(stride, buffer);
                DataBox box = new DataBox(buffer.DataPointer, stride, 1);

                a_context.UpdateSubresource(box, t2d, D3D11.Resource.CalculateSubResourceIndex(0, 0, CountMips(bsource.Size.Width, bsource.Size.Height)));
            }
            buffer.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler.DoErrorHandling(ex, ErrorHandler.GetCurrentMethod(ex), Environment.StackTrace);

        }
        return t2d;
    }
```

Comment: I'm being forced to  load (WPF) System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource to a Texture2D of which is put on a quad.